# How to get multilple row of data into 1 row with different column name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the written the following query :

```
select user_id, id ,value 
from users us 
left join masterdata md 
    on md.id = us.id
left join masterdatatemp mdt 
    on mdt.id = us.id
where id = 6 and value = 1
   or id = 6 and value = 0 
order by id
```

The above query returns:

```
User_Id ID VALUE
6       55  1
6       55  0
6       84  0
6       84  1
```

But I want the output like:

```
 User_Id    ID VALUE1  VALUE2
    6       55  1       0
    6       84  0       1
```

How can I convert my multiple rows to single column with different column name?

Comment: Please provide the table structure and Raw data example.  And also a better description of the "wanted result".  In general you can use sub-select, outer-apply, case clauses, and a multitude of other options to format your result set.  But the raw structure and data examples are needed.

Comment: Does it always 2 values => 2 columns? Or there can be VALUE3, ... ?

Comment: Your `where` clause say value should be 1 or 2. But your query returns value 0 and 1... Very odd.

Comment: if it's just two values, `select user_id, id, min(value) value1, max(value) value2... group by user_id, id` would give you what you want

Comment: @Razzka yes its has only 2 values only.

Comment: How do you decide where to place 1 and 0? Why not 6, 55, 0, 1 and 6, 84, 0, 1 instead?

Answer (score 0):

I tried as below, please modify as per your requirement

```
declare @user table(Userid varchar(max),ID int,value int)
insert into @user values (6,55,1)
insert into @user values (6,55,0)
insert into @user values (6,84,0)
insert into @user values (6,84,1)
select * from @user

declare @val varchar(max),@user_id varchar(max),@VAL1 INT ,@VAL2 INT
declare @values table(val int,id int identity(1,1))
declare @new_table table (Userid varchar(max),ID int,Value1 int,Value2 int)

declare c cursor for 
select distinct id,Userid from @user
open c
fetch next from c into @val,@user_id
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
begin
    insert into @values select value from @user where id= @val

    SET @VAL1=(select top 1 val from @values)
    SET @VAL2=(select val from @values where id not in (select top 1 id from @values))
    insert into @new_table values (@user_id,@val,@VAL1,@VAL2)
    delete from @values
    fetch next from c into @val,@user_id
end
close c
deallocate c
select * from @new_table
```

Comment: Please modify this code into your script . I just create d as per your requirement